Sources on the house of Ithamar before and after the Babylonian exile
According to Ezekiel 44, the sins of the house of Ithamar contributed to the exile of the Jewish people to Babylon. I'm interested in learning more about:
What specific sins are attributed to the house of Ithamar in biblical or extra-biblical sources?
What happened to the descendants of Ithamar after the exile?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127825/which-mishmar-did-the-descendants-of-eli-kohen-gadol-belong-to/127837#127837; https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118838/what-were-some-of-the-names-of-the-24-families-of-kohanim/118855#118855
